# does "set up" here means "place it or build it somewhere"?

Tags: meaning

does "set up" here means "place it or build it somewhere"?

Finally, the professors bought five hundred feet of new rope, bored with
holes the cabinet **set up** in one of their rooms, and trussed the boys in
what is described as a brutal manner. All the knots in the rope were tied
with linen thread, and one of their number, Professor Pierce, took his
place in the cabinet between the two brothers.

Comment: ...the cabinet _which was set up_ or _was_ in one of their rooms,

Comment: Or the cabinet was [**positioned**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/position) there. As an experiment, it was a [**set-up**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/set-up). But these days, we would know that *both* sides were a set-up, and instead be (perhaps) enthralled by [**divine particles**](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47525/have-divine-particles-spontaneously-appeared-in-an-indian-ashram).